# Is there an encyclopedia of mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

For example - for set complements, it would include all common notations such as 'A - B' or 'A \ B'

Comment: There is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) list on wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

[List of mathematical symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject)

[Table of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_mathematical_symbols&oldid=981751288)

Comment: Huh. I can't believe I missed the second source. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols
You can most probably get all mathematical symbols here.